# How does IsMouseButtonPressed() in Logitech Lua API work exactly?

Tags: lua, mouse, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I want to make a simple script, with which the mouse release and press the right mouse button automatically when I hold the right mouse button. But I come across a wird problem.

Lua code:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
    repeat
        ReleaseMouseButton(3)
        OutputLogMessage("RELEASED.\n")
        
        Sleep(300)
        rbPressed = IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        PrintBool(rbPressed)
        
        --PressMouseButton(3)
        OutputLogMessage("PRESSED.\n")  
    until not rbPressed
end
```

When I comment out the `PressMouseButton(3)` as above, press down the right mouse button with **enough time (>300ms)** and release the button, I get the following log:

> Event: MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED Arg: 2
> RELEASED.
> ***True***
> PRESSED.
> RELEASED.
> True
> PRESSED.
> RELEASED.
> False
> PRESSED.
> Event: MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED Arg: 2
> RELEASED.
> False
> PRESSED.

As you can see the `rbPressed` after the release is `True`, it seems to be the state of pysical mouse button, not the simulated release action. However, the `rbPressed` becomes `False` with the `PressMouseButton(3)` line. The log:

> Event: MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED Arg: 2
> RELEASED.
> ***False***
> PRESSED.
> Event: MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED Arg: 2
> RELEASED.
> False
> PRESSED.

How could this be? since the `PressMouseButton(3)` line is behind the `IsMouseButtonPressed(3)` line, it shouldn't influence the **FIRST** output of `rbPressed`.

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see the rbPressed after the release is True, it seems to be the state of pysical mouse button, not the simulated release action.

`IsMouseButtonPressed` returns simulated button, not physical.

`ReleaseMouseButton(3)` was ignored because `PressMouseButton(3)` was not called before.
There is an internal counter, `PressMouseButton` increases it, `ReleaseMouseButton` decreases.
When the counter = 0, `ReleaseMouseButton` is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. But if `IsMouseButtonPressed()` only returns simulated button, `rbPressed` should stay `false` when `PressMouseButton()` is commented out.

Comment: Button bindings also simulate press/release when physical button is pressed/released.  Remove RMB binding and try again, `rbPressed` will be `false`

Comment: It's true that `rbPressed` stay `False` after remove the default `Secondary Key` binding from physical `G2` button in G HUB, but what has happened and makes 'rbPressed' become `True` after a `ReleaseMouseButton(3)` action when hold on `G2` button with `Secondary Key` binding?

Comment: If it's because `Secondary Key` binding makes a `PressMouseButton(3)` action once, then `RealeaseMouseButton(3)` before `rbPressed` shouldn't be ignored. If `Secondary Key` binding make `PressMouseButton(3)` action continuously or locks the value of `IsMouseButtonPressed(3)`, then `rbPressed` should stay `True` regardless of commenting out `PressMouseButton(3)` or not.

Comment: *Secondary Key binding makes a PressMouseButton(3) action once* - The binding does not invoke `PressMouseButton`, it simulates key press without affecting the counter.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand why `rbPressed` becomes `True` after `ReleaseMouseButton(3)` since the binding don't change the counter.

Comment: Because `ReleaseMouseButton(3)` was ignored due to counter = 0

Comment: Sorry. What I mean is what makes `rbPressed` became `True` since the binding don't change the counter.

Comment: IsMouseButtonPressed does not return the counter.  The counter only restricts release-without-press behavior in Lua code.